# Numerical integration precision issue

Tags: numerical-integration

```
 theta = 1/10;
 ep = 15;
 w2 = 10;
 c = 1/2;
 rho[t_] := 1 + c Sin[  w2 t ];
 h = 1/2;
 S1 = ep;

sbar[t_] := ep rho[t];
S = rho[t] sbar[t];
sol = NDSolve[{D[g[x, t], 
 t] == (x (1 - x))/(2 rho[t]) D[g[x, t], x, x] -  (x (1 - x) ep)/
  2 D[  g[x, t], x], g[x, 0] == 0  , g[1, t] == 0, 
 g[0, t] == theta rho[t] (1 - Exp[-1000000 t]) }, 
g, {t, 0, (120 Pi)/w2}, {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
f[x_, t_] := (g /. sol[[1, 1]])[x, t];

 w2/(8 Pi) NIntegrate[
 f[x, t], {x, 0.00001, 1 - 0.00001}, {t, (108 Pi)/w2, 116 Pi/w2}]
(******analytics answer**)
theta (1. - 1/ep)
```

There is a numerical error in the above integral, i am sure the answer is not correct and it gives me error too, i tried using working precision and max recursion but could not resolve the error.

Comment: Did you recognize the `NDSolve messages`?

Comment: I am sorry sir, i don't know how to resolve this error.

Comment: What `Message` did `NDSolve` or `NIntegrate` give?

Comment: @MichaelE2 `NDSolveValue::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 4409.8008907054445` at t = 37.69911184307751886155172059935403461037`30. in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 25 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options.`

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich. Then the question should be about `NDSolve` and `NIntegrate` should be removed from the question. If the `NDSolve` problem is fixed, then a  separate question about `NIntegrate` may be asked if still necessary.

Comment: @MichaelE2 How to resolve the NDSolve error tolerance issue, and this is not a warning because the numerical answer is wrong and also solution given by Ulrich does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the boundary condition `g[0, t] == theta rho[t] (1 - Exp[-1000000 t])`. The part `(1 - Exp[-1000000 t])` changes from zero to 1 in nearly `dt=10^-6` time shift.

Try to increase `dt`

```
dt=0.01; 
G = NDSolveValue[{D[g[x, t],t] == (x (1 - x))/(2 rho[t]) D[g[x, t], x, x]- (x (1 - x) ep)/2 D[g[x, t], x], g[x, 0] == 0, g[1, t] == 0,
g[0, t] == theta rho[t] (1 - Exp[-  (t/dt)])}, 
g, {t, 0, (120 Pi)/w2 }, {x, 0, 1} ] 

Plot3D[G[t, x], {t, 0, (120 Pi)/w2}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All,AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "G[t,x]"}]
```

[image]

Solution doesn't change if you reduce `dt` further more!

Check result

```
w2/(8 Pi) NIntegrate[G[x, t], {x, 0 , 1 }, {t, (108 Pi)/w2, 116 Pi/w2}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
(*0.0873137*)
```

Comment: The answer is not correct ulrich. why i kept 10^-6 to match the boundary condition g(0,0) should be 0.  Actually the conditions are g(1,t)=0, g(x,0)=0 and g(0,t)= theta rho[t] (1-delta(t))

Comment: In my answer `g[0,0]==0`, numerical solution seems to be correct.